# One word for "to make someone addicted to something"

Tags: synonyms, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I need to know if there's a one word to get the meaning "to make someone addicted to something". Be it bad or good, something like, gaming, photography, reading, playing a musical instrument, using drugs, smoking etc. Like, when you say, 'a fanatic footballer' or 'a fanatic gamer' or 'a photography enthusiast', or 'a drug addict' etc. I want to know the word you say to the person who made that person, addicted to, fanatic to, attached to,.. that habit or the activity.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Perhaps, the person who **initiated** or **introduced** them ...

Comment: _Addict_, like many verbs, can be used as a causative. _They addicted him to heroin as part of their torture_. P.S. The verb _addict_ is stressed on the second syllable, while the noun _addict_ is stressed on the first. To adDICT, but an ADdict.

Comment: We can use 'addict' as a transitive verb - "Moriarty kidnapped Holmes, addicted him to heroin and began the process of trying to break him.", "in _The French Connection II_ [...] they tied Popeye Doyle down and forcibly addicted him to heroin" - not just drugs - "As a child, the boy wanted to become a firefighter or captain of a ship, but then a fellow violinist addicted him to music.".

Comment: If you want to use casual language, you could say they "hooked him on" something.